# Login interface completely changed in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, login, xfce

My hard drive got full yesterday and some weird things started to happen, like uGet not working anymore and the trash can not emptying. I switched to another OS and cleaned some stuff in the Xubuntu's partition. However, when I restarted the computer, the login GUI changed to this and I can't fix it.

[image: Ugly login GUI image]

Does anyone know how to get back the original Xfce interface?

Comment: Turns out that I tried to download the XDM download manager (uGet wasn't working) and installed a display manager called xdm instead. The reconfigure command worked, I switched back to the lightdm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't konow which displaymanager Xubuntu uses normaly. But you can run the comand to reconfigure your Display manager:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

If it is missing try to install it:

```
 sudo apt install lightdm
```

Insead of `lightdm` you can also use `gdm3` wich is the default for Ubuntu (Gnome).